# Undo last action in vb.net in Catia

Tags: vb.net, undo, catia

I am trying to **Undo** last action in **Catia** via **vb.net**. I have tried (after grabbing catia object):

- CATIA.StartCommand("Undo")
- CATIA.StartCommand("Undo Empty selection")

no results. When I switch to CATIA window and press Ctr^Z undo works.
I don' want a user interaction in Catia so Undo with history just won't do.

Thanks for any input,
Anna

Answer (score 0):

Usually you cannot "undo" an action performed by scripts. Perhaps you can get a way to really undo the last action (like delete the product that was added, instead of "undo")?

Answer (score 0):

you should create break point before start process:

set name document: "PROCESS"

-- process...

while do name document = "PROCESS"

CATIA.StartCommand "Undo"

loop

'WORKING !!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).